# Полиморфизм подтипов на основе механизма наследования и на основе интерфейсов

Tags: java, ооп

Можно ли сказать, что полиморфизм подтипов реализуется с помощью  механизма наследования и с помощью **интерфейсов**?

Цитата: *Для представления типов в Java удобно использовать интерфейсы. С помощью интерфейса декларируется тип переменной, которая может указывать на объект любого класса, реализующего этот интерфейс.*

Покажите пожалуйста на примере как в Java представить тип с помощью интерфейса

Comment: `List myList`;  Может быть: `myList = new LinkedList(); myList = new ArrayList()` и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ли сказать, что полиморфизм подтипов реализуется с помощью механизма наследования и с помощью интерфейсов?

Да.

Различие только в том, где определяется интерфейс (набор публичных методов, которые могут быть использованы для вызова после декларации переменной данного типа)

Для механизма наследования интерфейс определяется публичными методами базового класса.

В случае использования интерфейса - публичные методы определяются в самом интерфейсе.

Также, различие в том, что при использовании полиморфизма подтипов на основе наследования в переменную можно записать только объекты классов-наследников данного типа. А для полиморфизма подтипов на основе интерфейса в переменную типа интерфейса можно записать вообще любой объект, созданный на основе любого класса, который декларирует имплементацию(реализует) объявленный интерфейс.